# For loop to perform a shooting search in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, searching, procedural-programming

First comes the disclosure: I am very new to *Mathematica* and not so much a numerical guy in general. I am having a hard time using the for loop routine in *Mathematica* the correct way as well as finding resources as how to do so.

I heard that we should avoid as possible using `For` loops in the first place in *Mathematica* but I don't see how I could use an alternative to solve my problem and I do not manage to make my for loop working.

Here is my problem: I want to find a way to search for an undefined boundary condition according to some smoothness condition by varying one of the initial condition. In my example I want to find the point for which both solution reaches zero at the same time. The algorithm should be able to

1. Make a guess for X0
2. Compute the Solution
3. If X reaches 0 before Y, increase the guess, otherwise decrease it
4. iterate until X(T) = Y(T) = 0

I manage to do 1 2 3 and but do not manage to get to update on my guess. Here is the code I was writing:

```
crit = 0.01;
f[x_] := If[Abs[x] < crit, 1, 0];

For[ite = 1; ql = 0; qh = 5; F0 = (ql + qh)/2; a = 100,

 ite < 100; f[a] > 0,

 ite++; ql = qlu; qh = qhu,

 sol = NDSolve[{y'[t] - 2 y[t] == 4 - t, x'[t] == 2 x[t] + 4 - t, 
y[0] == -1.5, x[0] == F0, 
WhenEvent[{x[t] == 0, y[t] == 0}, end = t; 
 "StopIntegration"]}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}];

xend = x[end] /. sol;
 yend = y[end] /. sol;
 a = First[xend] - First[yend];
 If[Abs[First[xend]] < crit, qlu = F0, qhu = F0];
 Print[qlu, qhu]

 ]
```

My two questions: 
1. How do I make *Mathematica* update my guess ? 
2. Am I right to use a `For` loop ? What could be an alternative (better) option ?

Comment: I guess it wouldn't hurt to make the `For` loop work in this case so that you can clarify your logic. It never starts because `f[100]=0`.  If you fix that you'll throw an error because `end` is never set (unless your initial guess is the solution).  A better approach would be to use `FindRoot`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: `WhenEvent[{x[t] == 0, y[t] == 0} ..` stops when x *OR* y is zero.  If you want both do `WhenEvent[x[t] == 0&&y[t] == 0,..`  (I suspect your system has no solution though )

Comment: make that no non-trivial solution..:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ODEs are:

```
y'[t] - 2 y[t] == 4 - t,
x'[t] == 2 x[t] + 4 - t
```

... they are equal!

So for getting `x` and `y` going to zero at the same time just do `x[0] = y[0]` ...

**Edit**

Now,more seriously, I believe you mis-engineered your example. Something more general (although not completely) is:

Please note that the functions are coupled now:

```
k[x0_?NumericQ] := Module[{res, s, f0},
   s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{
      y'[t] == 2 y[t] x[t] + 4 - t,
      x'[t] == 2 x[t] + 4 - t,
      y[0] == -1.5, x[0] == f0,
      WhenEvent[{x[t] == 0}, res =  y@t^2; "StopIntegration"],
      WhenEvent[{y[t] == 0}, res =  x@t^2; "StopIntegration"]},
     {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}, f0];
   s[x0];
   res];

Plot[k[f0], {f0, -2, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And we find the crossing as:

```
FindRoot[k[f0], {f0, -2}]
(* -0.907017 *)
```

Please note that the `res` values have been defined so that we can use `FindRoot[ ]` .... in this answer's history record you may find other approaches :)

**edit 2**

Somewhat more elegant

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"];
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  {y'[t] == 2 y[t] x[t] + 4 - t,
   x'[t] == 2 x[t] + 4 - t,
   y[0] == -1.5, x[0] == f0,
   WhenEvent[{x[t] == 0, y[t] == 0}, "StopIntegration"]},
  {x, y}, {t, 0, 20}, f0];
tf[t_] := InterpolatingFunctionDomain[Last@s[t]][[-1, -1]]
val[t_?NumericQ] := Subtract @@ (Through[s[t][tf[t]]]^2)
FindRoot[val[f0], {f0, -2}]
Plot[val[x], {x, -2, -10^-10}]

(* {f0 -> -0.907017} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]